# Why is /bin/true such a large file? How would I find the source code?

Tags: bash, coreutils

I just found out about `/bin/true` yesterday. I'm not a bash power user by any means, but I decided to check it out. I was surprised to find that it is a 22K file (Ubuntu 12.04), and not one of the smallest utilities in `/bin` (e.g. `kill` is smaller). This is really just curiosity, but is there are reason for it not to be a very small bit of code? How would I go about finding the source code for `/bin/true`?

Comment: `int main () { return 0; }` - 26 *characters* - and that's all that's necessary. Compiles and strips to 6K on my machine. GNU's source is [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/true.c).

Comment: An *empty* executable file would have also been interpreted as a script returning 0. But it looks nicer with 80 lines of C I guess ;)

Comment: Please see this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419697/why-are-true-and-false-so-large/419704#419704

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, looking into the sources of the coreutils tools, `true` *is* one of the smallest. It is smaller than `kill`, though larger than `false` which is the very smallest:

```
$ for i in src/*c; do wc -l $i; done | sort -nr | tail -11
78 src/true.c
74 src/operand2sig.c
73 src/sync.c
37 src/prog-fprintf.c
2 src/uname-uname.c
2 src/uname-arch.c
2 src/ls-vdir.c
2 src/ls-ls.c
2 src/ls-dir.c
2 src/lbracket.c
2 src/false.c
```

So, `true` has 78 lines, but only 58 of them are actually code (the rest are blank lines and comments):

```
$ grep . src/true.c | awk '{ if(/\/\*/){a=0} if(a){print} if(/\*\//){a=1}}' | wc
50
```

And yes, a lot of that (10 lines) are dedicated to the `usage` function. The program is still *tiny* though.

Also, the reason that `false` is tinier is that it simply calls `true`:

```
$ cat src/false.c
#define EXIT_STATUS EXIT_FAILURE
#include "true.c"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ dpkg -S /bin/true
coreutils: /bin/true
```

So the package which actually provides `/bin/true` file is `coreutils`.

Run the below command to download the source code of `coreutils`,

```
apt-get source coreutils
```

Answer (score 2):

`true` is part of the GNU coreutils.  Their [homepage is here](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), and there are download links for the source there.  With git, you can download the source using:

```
git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/coreutils
```

Comment: Thank you! And by viewing "true.c" I can begin to answer the rest of my question. It looks like a lot of code may be devoted to supporting --version and --help?

Comment: That, and anything that is linked in statically.  I haven't examined the build files myself.

Comment: @jkt123 You my be interest on my answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419697/why-are-true-and-false-so-large/419704#419704